# How to put Movesense into DFU mode with Nrf Connect

Tags: dfu

Can I put the [movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense) in DFU mode directly using the Nrf Connect App? How?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do DFU directly from Nrf Connect. The thinking was that people that make Movesense applications have their own mobile app so they can integrate the nRF toolkit library to it directly and use that to make the OTA firmware update. I can see how that makes updating a bit clumsy when developing (I do it myself a lot during testing).

Some useful tips:

- Keep nRF Connect / nRF Toolbox active so you can switch easily between the apps
- If you have your own mobile app, integrate the nRF DFU library so that you can do the update from your own app

I hope this helps.

*Full Disclosure: I work for Movesense team*